# Regular expression match either of the words or both as comma separated

Tags: regex

I have an input that can be either `public` or `internal` or comma separated `public` and `internal` in any order. Following are the all possible scenarios:

> public
>
> internal
>
> public,internal
>
> internal,public

To check if it's either `public` or `internal` I'm using the following regex:

```
(?:public|internal)
```

To check if they are comma separated and in any order, I'm using the following regex:

```
(?=.*public)(?=.*internal)
```

I'm having hard time merging these two regex-s together.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you care if the regex return true for `public,public`?

Comment: What about using string operations and check if your string contains public and contains internal?

Comment: Yes. It should be either of the 4 from the question.

Comment: @oschlueter Yes, that would be easy, but I have to use regex to match my requirements.

Comment: Not a "regular" regex, but this will work for you `(public,internal|internal,public|public|internal)`, even though I'm not sure what exactly you need to do. Usually we use regex when we can't use other regular strings-comparison (which doesn't seem to be the case here). https://regex101.com/r/jsVsDr/1

Comment: @Dekel Is it a bad practice to match Strings by regex?

Comment: It's not the usage. You can do so - but it really makes no sense. It's like to use a print function 5 times with each of the chars `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o` instead of use one print with the string `hello`. You can do both, it's just make no sense to use the latter.

Comment: @Dekel Got it. I'm using Hibernate validator. So I thought instead of creating new Validator, I'll use regex for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
(^public$|^internal$)|(^public,internal$|internal,public$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TSvqCX/1

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only four options, it is easy to match all four possibilities:

```
public|internal|public,internal|internal,public
```

You can use optional matching to "fold" four possible matches into two expressions:

```
public(?:,internal)?|internal(?:,public)?
```